# Is there a way to pick out the three biggest numbers from a sequence of number without using sort or list on Python?

Tags: python

I used loop and was able to find the biggest number, but then it puzzles me with how to find the rest two.

This is what I have so far

```
    a= int(input())
    b=0
    d=0
    e=0
    for i in range(0,a):
        c= int(input())
        if c>b:
        b=c

    print (b)
```

Comment: Can you explain why you wouldn't want to use a list or sort? Does your homework exercise permit you to use any other Python constructs such as dictionaries or sets?

Comment: You'll thank yourself if you give your variables descriptive names, rather than single letters.

Comment: It is more like a little challenge from my instructor, and I have worked on it for days. Kind of new to Python, well, programming.

Comment: So do I set names like the biggest, second biggest, etc?

Answer (score 0):

This is extremely clumsy and far better implemented by building a list, sorting and slicing but those options are not available so:

```
a = int(input())

x = float('-inf')
y = float('-inf')
z = float('-inf')

for _ in range(a):
    v = int(input())
    if (lo := min(x, y, z)) < v:
        if x == lo:
            x = v
        elif y == lo:
            y = v
        else:
            z = v
print(x, y, z)
```